# Magento - Page error after altering code slightly

Tags: magento

So I was editing a page for magento, simply adding a product brands slider, but it unfortunately somehow crashed the page. I reindexed everything and flushed cache to no avail. So I just reverted back to the old code, reflushed, but still the page is broken. The error report it has given me is;

```
a:5:{i:0;s:127:"Invalid method Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu::renderCategoriesMenuHtml(Array
(
[0] => 
[1] => 0
[2] => level-top
)
)";i:1;s:4574:"#0 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(43): Varien_Object->__call('renderCategorie...', Array)
#1 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml(43): Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu->renderCategoriesMenuHtml(false, 0, 'level-top')
#2 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home4/johnsoja...')
#3 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...')
#4 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#8 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#9 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('topMenu', true)
#10 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/header.phtml(108): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('topMenu')
#11 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home4/johnsoja...')
#12 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...')
#13 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#14 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#15 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('header', true)
#17 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/1column.phtml(42): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('header')
#18 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/home4/johnsoja...')
#19 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/ultimo...')
#20 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#26 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#27 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#28 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#29 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#31 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#32 /home4/johnsoja/public_html/magento1/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#33 {main}";s:3:"url";s:10:"/magento1/";s:11:"script_name";s:19:"/magento1/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

I am still very new to Magento, so all this really doesn't tell me much. I also would figure stripping the code post crash and reindexing should work, because I really didn't add much, but I may be completely mistaken on how it all works. Can anyone point me in a direction?! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like the file `app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml` at line 43 is calling

```
$this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml();
```

But actually that function `renderCategoriesMenuHtml()` is in the class `Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation` (whereas topMenu.phtml is running in class `Mage_Page_Block_Html_Topmenu`)

I suspect the root cause is an issue with an XML file, for example `app/design/frontend/ultimo/default/layout/local.xml` search for the block with the name 'topMenu' and look at its `type="page/html_topmenu"`

Now it gets a bit tricky for me. The block type should either be a theme specific block like `type="ultimo_page/html_topmenu"` assuming the file `app/code/local/ultimo/page/block/tml/topMenu.php` exists or else this 'topMenu' block needs to contain a nested block of `type="catalog/navigation"`.

To begin with it might be best to comment out that line 43 `$this->renderCategoriesMenuHtml();` to recover your Magento Store and then investigate how to render the category menu.

Comment: I've had the same problem and it was caused when I added a new local.xml layout file which overrode another that I wasn't aware of. Carrying over the part in `<reference name="top.menu">` to my new local.xml solved it.